# How to create the object of class where constructor is parameterized constructor using default access modifier

Tags: java

I am working enhancement project.
Here they created some classes using parameterized constructor using `default` access modifier. I want to create those classes object and use the methods for call business functionalities. packages are different.

```
public class CheckAmount {

    private double balance;

    CheckAmount(double balance){
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    .....
}
```

so how to create the object of classes.
Please provide different approches.. if possible.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Default access means that access is allowed within same package. So you need the `public` modifier. Another possibility is to introduce an indirection like a factory and dependency injection, but this is more advanced.